# where to put static wsdl file instead of dynamically generating the wsdl file on each request in php

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Am using NuSoap Webservice. My webservice endpointType is wsdl. The problem is am not able to connect and update the status.

This is my URL
http://abc.testsite.com/LMSCallbackService/LMSExternalOrientationService.svc

Dynamically generated WSDL file Soap address location should be
http://abc.testsite.com/LMSCallbackService/LMSExternalOrientationService.svc?wsdl

But the current Soap address location is like
http://**clwebwtrv4.colo**.testsite.com/LMSCallBackService/LMSExternalOrientationService.svc?wsdl [the link is wrong.]

How could I remove the bold items?

I searched the stuff in net, came up with the following solutions

> Use static wsdl file, instead of dynamic generation of wsdl file.

Note: don't know how to stop dynamic generation of wsdl file, also where to put the static wsdl file.

Questions:
- where to put static wsdl file?
- how to stop dynamic generation of wsdl file?

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

**Way to use static WSDL:**

Save the wsdl file to some location, use the physical path while calling.

`$url = 'http://www.testsite.com/abc/preprod_sunflower.wsdl'`

Ex: `$client = new nusoap_client($url,true);`

**Note:** in that WSDL file don't fotget to provide your proper 'Soap Address Location'.

Thats it. Hope its use full.

**Disadvantage:**

While updating the NuSoap, its creates some problem. So we need to update our WSDL file.